# Java regex for html select tag parsing

Tags: java, regex

I will be writing a program where I just read a jsp file line by line and using regex check if there are any `select` tags in the page. If they are then I want to extract the data between `<option>DATA</option>` tags.

I wrote the following regex [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lLbsVy/4).

```
(?:<select.*>\n?\s+(.*<option.*>$.*)\n?\s+<\/select>.*)
```

Those who are not aware about regex101, you can also see the java code for the regex using sidebar at top left.

Problem is regex is not matching any thing for the string:

```
<select name="javaType">
  <option value="boolean">boolean</option> 
  <option value="byte">byte</option> 
  <option value="char" selected>char</option> 
  <option value="double">double</option> 
  <option value="float">float</option> 
  <option value="int">int</option> 
  <option value="long">long</option> 
</select>
```

I want to extract the data between  tags. I know my regex is incomplete but I have no clue on how I should proceed on this.

Do I parse line by line and check for select tag first, then again check for  tags? Or is there a better way using regex?

Comment: To parse html, you can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org)

Comment: I can't for some reason, I only have the option of using regex.

Comment: "I can't for some reason" and what reason is that? Are you getting some problems while using it (errors/exceptions/incorrect results) or is it requirement from someone else (who probably didn't see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766, or [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) or [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166))? Can you show us your attempts using parser (maybe you missed some mistake on your part which we somehow will find)?

Comment: It's because of our client who is insisted on using regex only for this, I don't know what his problem is, but this is what was communicated to me

Comment: From my experience mass downvotes are often caused by belief that people shouldn't support choosing incorrect tools for the job (just like using `null` as layout manager in swing). HTML isn't regular language so it shouldn't be handled with *regular* expressions (see my earlier links). Proper tool here would be HTML parser. The more you use incorrect tool, the bigger your problem will be when you will face situation which will require from you moving to correct tool (and it almost certainly will happen since "the only thing that is constant is change"). So why not use proper tool at start?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use some html parser to process it? 
your question is not very specific though.

I thought you might want to check which option has been selected. 
I give a simple regex base on my understanding.

```
selected\>(?<selected>(\w+))<
```

The named pattern of `selected` is what has been selected.

Comment: For some reasons, its not possible for me to use html parser's, I have only option of using regex or something that won't require any additional jars in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `look aheads(?:)` in your regex to find the pattern. For this to work, all content needs to be in a single line. If you wanted to find a regex for `bash` then we could have used `tr -s '\n' ' '` to transform the string in one line and then maybe look ahead would have helped.

We can do something similar in java also but I would suggest you to loop through file lines one-by-one, search for `<select` and once you find it, have a regex to find content between `option` till you find `.

Hope below code helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String strTest = "D:\\Temp.jsp";
    File file = new File(strTest);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String strLine = "";
    boolean selectStartFound = false;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<option .*?>(.+?)</option>");
    Matcher matcher = null;
    while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!selectStartFound && strLine.toLowerCase().contains("<select")) {
            selectStartFound = true;
        }
        if (selectStartFound) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
        if (selectStartFound && strLine.toLowerCase().contains("</select>")) {
            selectStartFound = false;
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that matches:

```
/(?:<select.*?>.*?((<option.*?<\/option>\s*)+)<\/select>.*)/ims
```

By using the `s` option you can get rid of the mess of trying to match newlines as a special case.

The first capture group captures all of the option tags, the second capture group captures the last option tag. You might need to do this in two steps, processing what the first capture group captures to break it down into all of the separate option tags.

regex101: https://regex101.com/r/lLbsVy/5